# C++ Function that returns function, errors C2440, C2100 in xmemory and xrefwrap

Tags: c++, visual-c++, function-pointers

I am getting errors like:

```
Error   24  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'AttrValue'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory  208
Error   25  error C2100: illegal indirection    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 49
Error   26  error C2296: '.*' : illegal, left operand has type 'AttrValue'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 49
Error   37  error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'std::_List_const_iterator<_Mylist>' to 'AttrValue'   c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xmemory  208
Error   38  error C2100: illegal indirection    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 49
Error   39  error C2296: '.*' : illegal, left operand has type 'AttrValue'  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 49
```

It doesn't point to my code so I dont exactly know whats wrong. But looking at MSDN docs, I was thinking the problems maybe caused by:

```
function<bool(AttrValue)> QueryEvaluatorPrivate::getClausePredicate(Relation clauseType, int preferedIndex) {
    switch (clauseType) {
    case UsesRelation:
        if (preferedIndex == 0)
            return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsed;
        return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasStmtsUsing;
    case UsesPRelation:
        if (preferedIndex == 0)
            return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsedInProc;
        return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasProcsUsing;
    }
}
```

`hasVarsUsed` and other `has*` functions are just functions that return a `bool`. Is there something wrong with this?

**UPDATE**

Following @Cameron's comment, in the output window is **[output](http://pastie.org/7161975)**. I think the offending line is `output.insert(x)` (last line):

```
    ... 
    function<bool(AttrValue)> clausePredicate = getClausePredicate(cl.type, prefered);
    unordered_set<AttrValue> output;
    if (prefered == pos) {
        for (auto x = input.begin(); x != input.end(); ++x) 
            if (clausePredicate(*x)) 
                output.insert(x);
    ...
```

But whats wrong with that? Maybe I am looking at the wrong place?

**UPDATE 2**

Fixed the 1st problem `output.insert(x)` should be `output.insert(*x)`... but I have

```
Error   6   error C2100: illegal indirection    c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\xrefwrap 49
```

I think the offending line is:

```
return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsed;
```

I am probably returning functions wrongly?

```
// function declaration
bool QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsed(StmtNum s)
```

Comment: Look at the Output window in Visual Studio. It will show the template instantiation trace all the way back to your code (though often the error is still cryptic anyway).

Comment: Are you **sure** that none of your errors point to your own code?

Comment: @Cameron, nice tip. Fixed the 1st problem ... now I have illegal redirection. I think the offending line is: `return &QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsed`. Is that the right way to return a function?

Comment: But what is the data type of `input`?

Comment: @JiewMeng from your link to the error messages, your error is at **line 147 of queryevaluator_getcandidatelist.cpp**

Comment: @DrewDormann, yes I see nothing in the Errors window that points to my own code, but as Cameron points out. I found the problem in output window

Comment: @MihaiTodor, input is `unordered_set<AttrValue>`

Comment: Is `hasVarsUsed` a member function?

Comment: @JiewMeng Then you might want to insert *x, as Wacek pointed out...

Comment: You cannot bind a member function to a function object, because it would not be clear what object to call that member function on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use a function with the wrong signature, maybe because `StmtNum` is a derived class of `AttrValue`? Here's an example to explain:

```
#include <functional>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};

void fa( A ) {}
void fb( B ) {}

int main()
{
  std::function<void(A)> f1( &fa ); // OK
  std::function<void(A)> f2( &fb ); // fails
}
```

In your code, I see `function<bool(AttrValue)>`, but the function is

```
bool QueryEvaluatorPrivate::hasVarsUsed(StmtNum s);
```

Also, this function has to be static as you can not simply mix free (or static) functions with member functions when passing around pointers to them.

Answer (score 1):

x = input.begin() -> looks like x is some sort of iterator

Maybe you should do:

```
output.insert(*x)
```

instead of

```
output.insert(x)
```